# How to Test Timer with @Published?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a view which uses a `ObservableObject` which used an `Timer` to update seconds which are an `@Published` property.

```swift
class TimerService: ObservableObject {

    @Published var seconds: Int

    var timer: Timer?

    convenience init() {
        self.init(0)
    }
    
    init(_ seconds: Int){
        self.seconds = seconds
    }

    func start() {
      ...
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in 
      self.seconds += 1 }
      self.timer?.fire()
    }

    func stop() {...}

    func reset() {...}
}
```

To test this logic I tried to subscribe to the `seconds` var. The problem is that the .sink method only trigger once and never again, even when it should.

```swift
class WorkTrackerTests: XCTestCase {
    var timerService: TimerService!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        super.setUp()
        timerService = TimerService()
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        super.tearDown()
        timerService = nil
    }

    func test_start_timer() throws {
        var countingArray: [Int] = []
        
        timerService.start()
        timerService.$seconds.sink(receiveValue: { value -> Void in
            print(value) // 1 (called once with this value)
            countingArray.append(value)
            
        })
        timerService.stop()
        
        for index in 0...countingArray.count-1 {
            if(index>0) {
                XCTAssertTrue(countingArray[index] - 1 == countingArray[index-1])
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is there something I did wrong or is the SwiftUI @Published Wrapper not capable of being subscribed by something else than SwiftUI itself?

Comment: There is no need to test Apple's code. Don't test Timer. You know what it does. Test _your_ code.

Comment: As for your actual example test harness, it is flawed from top to bottom. A `sink` without a `store` will indeed get only one value, if it gets any at all. But the issue runs even deeper, as you are acting like your code will magically stop and wait for the timer to finish. It won't. You are saying stop _immediately_ after saying start. Asynchronous input requires asynchronous testing. You would need an expectation and a waiter.

Comment: But it is very unclear why you are subscribing to the publisher at all. What are you trying to find out? The only question of interest, it seems, is whether you are incrementing your variable each time the timer fires. And you can test that without a timer and without subscribing to a publisher.

Comment: @matt I would like to make sure that the timer doesn't stoo working somehow. It is basically a test to get into MacOS SwiftUI testing. Can you provide an example how to test this asynchronous? I couldn't find a solution to this online :(

Comment: How would the timer stop working? Again, you cannot / should not test Timer. You know what it does and it isn't yours.

Comment: And as I said, if you really really want to test something asynchronous, you need to use asynchronous testing. As I said, you do that with expectation and waiter. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by repeating what I said already in comments. There is no need to test Apple's code. Don't test Timer. You know what it does. Test *your* code.

As for your actual example test harness, it is flawed from top to bottom. A `sink` without a `store` will indeed get only one value, if it gets any at all. But the issue runs even deeper, as you are acting like your code will magically stop and wait for the timer to finish. It won't. You are saying `stop` immediately after saying `start`, so the timer never even runs. Asynchronous input requires asynchronous testing. You would need an expectation and a waiter.

But it is very unclear why you are subscribing to the publisher at all. What are you trying to find out? The only question of interest, it seems, is whether you are incrementing your variable each time the timer fires. And you can test that without subscribing to a publisher — and, as I said, without a Timer.

So much for the repetition. Now let's demonstrate. Let's start with the code you've actually shown, the only code that has content:

```
class TimerService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var seconds: Int
    var timer: Timer?
    convenience init() {
        self.init(0)
    }
    init(_ seconds: Int){
        self.seconds = seconds
    }
    func start() {
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
          self.seconds += 1
      }
      self.timer?.fire()
    }
}
```

Now look at all the commands you send to the Timer and encapsulate them in a Timer subclass:

```
class TimerMock : Timer {
    var block : ((Timer) -> Void)?
    convenience init(block: (@escaping (Timer) -> Void)) {
        self.init()
        self.block = block
    }
    override class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval,
            repeats: Bool,
            block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer {
        return TimerMock(block:block)
    }
    override func fire() {
        self.block?(self)
    }
}
```

Now make your TimerService a generic so that we can inject TimerMock when testing:

```
class TimerService<T:Timer>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var seconds: Int
    var timer: Timer?
    convenience init() {
        self.init(0)
    }
    init(_ seconds: Int){
        self.seconds = seconds
    }
    func start() {
      self.timer = T.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
          self.seconds += 1
      }
      self.timer?.fire()
    }
}
```

So now we can test your logic without bothering to run a timer:

```
import XCTest
@testable import TestingTimer // whatever the name of your module is
class TestingTimerTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() throws {
        let timerService = TimerService<TimerMock>()
        timerService.start()
        if let timer = timerService.timer {
            timer.fire()
            timer.fire()
            timer.fire()
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(timerService.seconds,4)
    }
}
```

None of your other code needs to change; you can go on using TimerService as before. I can think of other ways to do this, but they would all involve dependency injection where in "real life" you use a Timer but when testing you use a TimerMock.

Comment: In the original test the timer was never getting touched so it doesn’t make sense to say they were testing Apple’s code when from a testing perspective each called function is a black box. Here however you are reaching inside the service to be tested just so you can test the timer itself (which should probably be private). The point of a timer is that it gets called over time and this test basically ignores the time aspect which could be relevant given a Timer’s use. But also we don’t know how the Timer was set up, which is why it’s still relevant to test.

Comment: @keji You are free to say that but I don't agree. If the point is how the app behaves with the passage of time then you mock time too.

Comment: @keji And I don't agree about what the tests do or what the service does. You wouldn't object to my mocking a server if the function calls an API, the Timer is the same way. The only thing this particular service does is count how many times the Timer fires and we're testing exactly that.

Comment: I don’t get how it makes sense for seconds not to be the number of seconds from when start() was called (plus the initial amount). That’s why it’s called seconds. If they wanted to measure the number of times it was called then they should call it `times` or `count`. What if my TimerService setup the timer to fire every 0.5 seconds? Then seconds ends up being double the actual amount of seconds in reality but this test would still pass.

Comment: Also self is strongly captured and   given there is no way to stop the service in your code this would always lead to a reference cycle.